# Running React and Node at the same time.

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have a use case that I dont think is too unique but I am running into challenges. The application I have is written in express/EJS and is running on port 35, I want to include react so I am following a tutorial and am writing this app within my existing app and its running on another port. I can see both applications when they are on different ports, if I try to put them on the same port they conflict. duh. however I would like to run React within my app for certain features, how do I accomplish this? How can I run my node app and react at the same time?

My dependencies for my react app are:

```
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"webpack": "^1.14.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
```

My entire dependency tree is

```
 "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.4",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cloudinary": "^1.4.6",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "method-override": "^2.3.7",
    "moment": "^2.17.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.8",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "nodemailer": "^2.7.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "xoauth2": "^1.2.0"
  },
```

the top list is just the ones I loaded for the tutorial. So maybe to run React in Node I dont need the webserver aspect of react, if there is one? Or is that just using node?

Here is the webpack.config.js file.

```
const webpack =require('webpack'),
path    =require('path');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const config =  {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is the scripts in the pacakge.json file. This has the code with the port and such:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start":"npm run build",
    "build":"webpack -d && sudo cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --port 35",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

To run the nodejs and reactjs app simply follow these steps:

1. **npm i concurrently --save**
2. Then add these scripts in **composer.json** of your nodejs app,

   `"scripts": {
   "start": "node server.js", //For starting node server with **npm run start**
   "react": "npm start --prefix react", // --prefix react indicates the folder of your react app
   "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run react\""
   },`
3. Then add,

   `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"  //Add your own port where nodejs app is running`
   to your react **composer.json** file.
4. Then finally run **npm run dev** to start the react and node app concurrently.

For more information visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently .