# How to run an express server with create react app?

Tags: node.js, express, create-react-app

I’m using create react app as a project outline and when you run npm start it runs the react server with node. I have added express with MySQL and want to run this server at the same time in my server.js file. How can set this to run this when I deploy my server? At the moment it’s only running react-scripts and not this server file and my database isn’t working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running React and Node at the same time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388418/running-react-and-node-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 terminals, one for front end, one for backend